# Finding if current row is last row to be selected from database

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, postgresql-9.1, window-functions

I am selecting list of periods from database. If current row is first row then the period starts with date and I can find the interval between period start like this:

```
SELECT
...
CASE WHEN row_number() OVER(ORDER BY r.created_at ASC) = 1 THEN r.created_at - r.created_at::date ELSE NULL END AS period
...
FROM mytable r
```

**How can I do the same to *last* row?** To find the time between the r.created_at of last row and midnight of its date.

I am aware of `first` and `last` functions in PostgreSQL (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)), but they are aggregate functions and do not help in this case.

Edit:
This question has 2 great answers. Neither of them help in my case, as this single line i presented as part of my question is part of bigger query, put together programmatically and using the solutions offered would force me to alter alot of code, which i am not willing to do at this point. Should the scaling problems hit - then i will certainly reconsider.

Comment: How about doing the same but with `DESC` instead of `ASC`?

Comment: If you order by (... DESC) the last row wil be the first ...

Comment: Hmm that might actually work. Thanks. i have to test it now :)

Comment: Do you need the result ordered by `created_at` anyway?

Comment: Thanks - it worked just fine using DESC instead of ASC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be faster than window functions:

```
with r as (
    select
        min(created_at) as min_created_at,
        max(created_at) as max_created_at
    from mytable
)
select
    case when (select min_created_at from r) = created_at
    then created_at - created_at::date else null
    end as period_min,
    case when (select max_created_at from r) = created_at
    then created_at - created_at::date else null
    end as period_max
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [window functions `first_value()` and `last_value()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a *single* `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN ts IN ( first_value(created_at) OVER w
                       , last_value(created_at)  OVER w)
       THEN created_at::time::interval ELSE NULL END AS period
FROM   tbl
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY created_at rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                          AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

Special requirement here: you need to adjust the [**frame definition**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for the `last_value()` call. By default it is:

```
RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

But you need:

```
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
```

The `first_value()` call would work with the default frame, but can use the same as well.

I also simplified computation of `period`. Your definition coincides with the `time` component of a `timestamp.` Just cast to `time` to "truncate" the date part: `created_at::time`.
Casting to `interval` after that is just to return the same data type as your original query.

The result will be ordered by `created_at` automatically due to the current implementation of window functions. But do not rely on that. If you need sorted output, add to the end explicitly:

```
ORDER BY created_at
```